# Replying to answers?

Tags: support

What's the proper way to reply-back or discuss something with someone who answered your question?  What if they ask a question in their answer?

Thanks,
Neal

P.S.  I'm adding this bulletin after the first 3 answers appeared - I have JavaScript on - but the "Add Comment" doesn't work for me in Firefox 3.5.  And in IE7, no "Add comment" link even appears.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to simply edit your question to add the requested information - that way, it's immediately available to *everyone* answering the question.

If your response is specific to a single answer, then leave a comment. Note that [this requires a reputation of at least 50](https://stackoverflow.com/faq); if you have yet to achieve this, then stick with editing the question.

#### See also:

[How should a Questioner respond to answers in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/how-should-a-questioner-respond-to-answers-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: +1 If it's a yes, no, or quick comment then it goes in the comment. If more details is requested, or I have something to say that is longer than the length of a comment, then I edit. I will often note that I have commented in an edit, this makes it abundantly clear to everyone concerned.

Comment: Well - if I need 50 to do "Add Comment" then it's very strange -because I can do it in IE7 but not FireFox 3.5.

Comment: I don't recall if that limit applies to answers to your own questions or not, but pretty sure it doesn't apply to commenting on your questions themselves. Can't imagine why FF 3.5 would be giving you trouble - i'm using it myself. You've probably tried this already, but - be sure to disable NoScript, and then hit Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

Comments. Use Comments.

There is a little 'Add Comments' button under each answer and question.

Comment: In Firefox I click "Add Comment" and absolutely nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use Comments to answer answers.